# How to access attributes of XML using DataFrame and com.databricks.spark.xml format?

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am having a xml file like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<paml version="2.0" xmlns="paml20.xsd">
  <kmData type="partial">
    <header>
      <log dateTime="2016-11-10T07:01:37" action="created">partial used</log>
    </header>
    <Object class="SSC" version="0.3" dName="p2345" id="600">
    <list name="sscOptions">
        <p>0</p>
        <p>1</p>
        <p>2</p>
        <p>3</p>
        <p>4</p>
      </list>
    <p name="AAA">2</p>
      <p name="BBB">3</p>
      <p name="CCC">NNN</p>
      <p name="DDD">26</p>
      <p name="EEE">30</p>
      <p name="FFF">30</p>
      <p name="GGG">80</p>
      <p name="HHH">20</p>
      <p name="III">100</p>
      </Object>
    <Object class="PLUS2" version="0.5" dName="p2346" id="700">
      <p name="AAA">5</p>
      <p name="BBB">1</p>
      <p name="CCC">0</p>
      <p name="DDD">0</p>
      <p name="EEE">0</p>
      <p name="FFF">0</p>
      <list name="PLUS2Out">
        <p>0</p>
        <p>0</p>
        <p>0</p>
        <p>0</p>
        <p>0</p>
        <p>0</p>
      </list>
      <p name="GGG">8</p>
      </Object>
   </kmData>
 </paml>
```

Here I want to extract

```
dateTime,class,version,dName,id,AAA,CCC from Object class ="SSC" and 
dateTime,class,version,dName,id,AAA,BBB,CCC from object class PLUS2.
```

And I want to write to a file.

I have tried the code below.

```
package Dataframeparsing
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import scala.xml.XML

object Dataframeparse {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("Parse XML Data").setMaster("local[*]"))

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
    .option("rowTag", "Object")
    .load("D://userdata//sam//Desktop//abc.xml")
    print("xml file read done")
    val Data1 = df.filter("class = 'SSC'")
    val D1store=Data1.select("AAA","CCC").show()
    D1store.write.option("header", "true").csv("file:///C:/out1.csv")
    val Data2 = df.filter("class = 'PLUS2'")
    val D2store=Data2.select("AAA","BBB","CCC").show()
    D2store..write.option("header", "true").csv("file:///C:/out2.csv")
}
}
```

When I tried the above code I am getting error below:

> 17/02/21 18:16:12 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (treeAggregate at InferSchema.scala:60) finished in 14.905 s
>   17/02/21 18:16:12 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: treeAggregate at InferSchema.scala:60, took 15.088996 s
>       xml file read doneException in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'AAA' given input columns p, class, dName, defaults, list, version, id;
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)

I want the final ouput as below:

For `class=SSC`

```
2016-11-10T07:01:37,SSC,0.3,p2345,600,2,NNN
```

For `class=PLUS2`

```
2016-11-10T07:01:37,PLUS2,0.5,p2346,700,5,1,0
```

Comment: after `val df = .....` add a new line of `df.show(10)` and add the output of this command to your question

Comment: @khumar did you figured this out?